# notepad regular expression replacement

Tags: regex, notepad++

Essentially I have a set of name like

```
name1,
name2,
name3,
```

and I'd like to make it via find & replacement in notepad++

```
name1 = name1,
name2 = name2,
name3 = name3,
```

I have no problem find those name1 name2 in **Find what:**

```
[^\s,]+
```

But in **Replace with** , what should I do to replace ',' with "= **whatever being find**," ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find what (assuming your regex finds what you want correctly): `[^\s,]+`

Replace with: `$0 = $0`

`$0` means everything matched by the expression in "Find what"

Comment: The other post also works with extra group capture ().([^\s,]+)

Comment: Lol man deleted the other post too fast before I can up vote it !

Comment: nhahtdh, is $0 notepad++ specific regular expression ? while the capturing one is not ?

Comment: @Gob00st: `$0` works in Java, PCRE (what Notepad++ uses). Not in JavaScript, though, where `$&` is equivalent. Not sure for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following regex on search field:

^(\w+\d),

and the replace field:

$1 = $1,

Hope it help you!